# No module named 'psycopg2' and Error: pg_config executable not found. when trying to install on RHEL 7

Tags: python, linux, rhel

I run into the error while running my python code.

```
import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

But when I try to install psycopg2 , I get the other saying :

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

Found couple of answers working for Ubuntu that din't work on RHEL

Comment: `# yum install python-psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the pg_config is error due to the missing file. There are couple of libraries that have worked for folks. pg_config is in postgresql-devel for the RHEL7.

Running `yum install postgresql-devel` did the trick for me! Make sure you run it as Root.